# Solaris - get the remote host associated with each TCP connection

Tags: solaris

On Solaris, how can I get the remote IP or hostname associated with each TCP connection?

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED |
    sed -e 's/\.\([^.]*\) / \1/g' -e 's/  */ /g' |
    nawk '
    BEGIN {format="%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\n";
    printf(format,"local_host","local_protocol","remote_host","remote_protocol")}
    {printf(format,$1,$2,$3,$4)}'
```

Comment: So fancy... I would just do `netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED`

Comment: @Kamil The question asks for the remote host so I believe isolating it from the port/protocol is a good idea. The extra stuff provides filtering, headers and properly aligned columns, arguably more understandable than raw netstat output.

Comment: When I list the open TCP connections using `lsof`. Instead of seeing something like `hostname1:port1->ipaddress:port2 (IDLE)`, I see `*:* (IDLE)`. Why might a TCP connection have an apparent wildcard hostname and port like that? Specifically when it is IDLE.

Comment: These are unbound sockets, there no associated connection for them.

Comment: What might create such a socket?

Comment: These sockets do not use that much resources. A server might create a pool of them. They stay in that state until they are bound to an IP/port.

Comment: @jlliagre OK thanks. I am experiencing a program creating a very large number (around 7000) of IDLE TCP connections with `*:*` as the host information, which is actually causing a problem because it is blowing the file descriptor limit of the process.

Comment: 7000 idle sockets looks indeed quite a bit. You might workaround the issue by increasing the max number of file descriptor allowed to the process but identifying the root cause would be better.